# Google Drive API / GUI exports invalid PDF - not readable by iText7

Tags: c#, pdf, google-drive-api, google-docs, itext7

I'm trying to export multiple Google Docs files via Google Drive API into Pdf and merge them into one using **iText7** but it throws exception **iText.IO.Exceptions.IOException: 'PDF header not found.'** because of the weird PDF format from Google export.

Google Disk generated PDF content (read with notepad) is not valid PDF.

File content starts like this **倥䙄ㄭ㐮┊ㄊ** instead of something like **%PDF-1.4**

The uploaded PDF file is readable from Google Disk without any problem and it is readable even if I export the Stream directly to the disk. **File content is exactly the same when I download file manually through Google Docs GUI.**

Here is my code to export files via API:

```
var mimeType = "application/pdf";
var file = GetFile(sourceFile);
var pdfRequest = _driveService.Files.Export(sourceFile, mimeType);
var stream = pdfRequest.ExecuteAsStream();
```

Then I'm uploading PDF back into Google Drive via it's API

```
var newFile = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
newFile.MimeType = mimeType;
newFile.Parents = new List<string>() { targetFolder };

var createRequest = _driveService.Files.Create(newFile, stream, mimeType);
createRequest.SupportsAllDrives = true;
var createResult = createRequest.Upload();
```

Weirdly enough the format of exported PDF is ok when I use
`var text = pdfRequest.Execute();` instead of `pdfRequest.ExecuteAsStream` (it starts with %PDF-1.7).
But `Execute()` returns string instead of Stream.

Is there any way to get standard PDF format from Google Disk API or convert it in any possible way?

Comment: Here is the link for a pdf, that was generated from API and saved from the stream - https://www.dropbox.com/s/br8scibx6hxjs71/test_pdf_stack_overflow.pdf?dl=0

I've been wrong when i wrote that the content of pdf export of docs file from Google Docs GUI is "exactly the same". Export of the google doc is actually valid. The problem must be in the stream from the "ExecuteAsStream" method. I suppose that I'm doing something wrong when I write the stream into new Google disk File.

Comment: Well, as you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Apis/latest/Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest-1#Google_Apis_Requests_ClientServiceRequest_1_Execute) the ```Execute()``` method returns a **TResponse** object which the **.NET API** will understand as a valid pdf and treat it that way. However, the ```ExecuteAsStream()``` method will return a stream of bytes that the **.NET API** cannot treat as the source for a pdf file. I have not found any way to transform such stream into a valid pdf file, so I am afraid that using ```Execute()``` is your best option.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was in the **iText7** itself. It considered PDF as invalid but it probably just does not support PDFs in iso8859_2 encoding.
I tried to use **PDFSharp** instead and everything went smoothly.

I've used `ExecuteAsStream()` from Google Disk API to get PDF Stream with no problems at all so it wasnt at fault.

Thanks for all your tips.

Comment: There is nothing like *"PDFs in iso8859_2 encoding"*. Thus, i assume the PDF *is* invalid and PDFSharp simply is more successful in repairing it when loading it.